# Numerical instability of the axis-angle representation of rotations in 3D

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, applied-mathematics

Suppose that I have $1000$ pair of points where each pair consists of a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its image after a rotation in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ with some noise. I have used RANSAC to find the matrix representation of the rotation (which is unknown to us) and since the number of inliers is not very large, the answer is accurate up to $2$ decimal points in each entry only.  I have used the $L^2$ norm to determine inliers.

It turns out that even though the matrix representation is accurate up to $2$ decimal points, the axis-angle representation is highly unstable. I have tried to implement RANSAC using the axis-angle representation from scratch, and I have also tried to implement it using the matrix representation and then convert the answer to the axis-angle repesentation. Each time I run the algorithm, I get a direction that looks almost completely different from the last time. The angle is more or less the same, but the direction of the axis is very unstable.

I suppose that I need to use a different cost function for determining inliers. Is there a cost function that is known to give better numerically stable results for the axis-angle representation of rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

**Addendum:**

It turns out that if I use RANSAC with the matrix representation of rotations and then I find the eigenvectors of the solution to find the direction (the direction has to be the eigenvector that is a real vector), it is stable. However, if I use RANSAC with the axis-angle representation, the result is still highly unstable.

Comment: Do you have a small rotation? That would explain why the rotation axis is unstable.

Comment: @user100927 It's not "very" small. Running the algorithm several times says that the angle is probably close to $0.89$ radians.

Comment: you compute an approximation of a linear transformation, but how do you make sure that what you compute is an (approximate) rotation, and not something more general? This might explain why your attempts to convert it to a rotation are basically not working.

Comment: it could also be that your 1000 points lie in a subspace (or a close to this), then here is no uniqueness in the choice of a rotation...

Comment: @Dima  For the case of the matrix representation, at each iteration of RANSAC, I take $3$ random points. I compute the nearest rotation matrix that sends the three points to their alleged destinations. Then I use this nearest rotation to compute inliers and so on. Also, I have verified that the final answer is indeed an orthogonal transformation with determinant $1$. Edit: I have also added a few lines in my algorithm to remove those points where the axis-angle representation can fail. My $1000$ points didn't contain any such points though.

Comment: what is "the nearest rotation"? In what matrix norm? Imagine for a second you are trying to find a nearest rotation to a non-rotation, e.g. to a reflection...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik  The nearest rotation in the Frobenius norm. See this question for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86539/closest-3d-rotation-matrix-in-the-frobenius-norm-sense

Comment: why won't you instead use least absolute deviations to compute the approx. transform and prune outliers? you data set is small enough for this, I think.

Comment: One way or another, you would like to try to enforce orthogonality of the matrix early on, see my answer below.

Comment: this is also called the procrustes problem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try to enforce orthogonality of the matrix early on, and this seems possible: say, you have a pair of points $u,v$ and the unknown matrix $A$ so that $Au=v$. Now, if $A$ is orthogonal, i.e. $A^\top A=AA^\top=I$, then from $A^\top Au=u=A^\top v$ you get more conditions on $A$, for free. More precisely, you get 6 conditions from 1 pair of points, and from 1.5 pairs, so to speak, you should be able to get your 9 entries of an orthogonal $A$.