# Finding the closest special orthogonal matrix in Frobenius norm sense

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, linear-programming

Given a $3\times3$ matrix $M$, if we would like to get the closest $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ matrix $R$ that minimizes
\begin{equation}
  \|R-M\|_F
\end{equation}

then $R$ = $UV^{T}$ where $U$ and $V^{T}$ are the orthogonal matrices from the singular value decompositon of $M$. i.e. $M = U\Sigma V^{T}$ as explained in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86539/closest-3d-rotation-matrix-in-the-frobenius-norm-sense). When $UV$ is not a "special" orthogonal matrix i.e. $det(UV^{T}) = -1$ we replace the singular vector $u_3$ by $-u_3$.

My question is why only $u_3$ and why not any other column of $U$ or row of $V^{T}$?

(Posting this as a question instead of a comment since I don't have enough reputation yet, sorry!)

Comment: You must mean $\det(UV^{T}) = -1$

Comment: Oops, yes thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By right-multiplying both $R$ and $M$ by $V$ and left-multiplying by $U^T$ you are leaving the objective invariant. Now the new $M$ is diagonal (actually, it's $\Sigma$), and it's not hard to convince yourself that so should the new $R$ be. If $\det(UV^T) = -1$, then the constraint means $R$ is a diagonal matrix with $\pm 1$ as its diagonal entries, and an odd number of $-1$s. Since $\Sigma$ is nonnegative, the choice that minimizes the distance is to make the entry corresponding to the smallest diagonal entry in $\Sigma$ the sole $-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am able to convince myself that the new rotation $R'$ (after left-multiplying and right-multiplying $R$) should be diagonal, but I am unable to understand why it should have a determinant of -1. I think the old rotation, $R$, should have a determinant of -1 (to make $det(U^{T}RV) = 1$ when det(UV^{T} = -1), but then it need not be diagonal?

Comment: The old rotation R is what you constrain to be in SO(3), so it needs to be determinant 1. If you let $R' = U^T R V$, then you need $\det R' = -1$.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. And negating the last element of $\Sigma$ is equivalent to negating the smallest singular vector of $U$. And we know $R = UV^{T}$. But what seems a little unintuitive to me here is that we're modifying our input $M$ itself to minimize the objective.