# How to project a matrix to a unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, orthogonal-matrices

Given a nonzero vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we all know that it's projection onto the unit $\ell_2$ ball is just $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$. Let $X$ be some nonzero $n \times n$ matrix. What is the projection of $X$ onto the unitary matrices? In other words, which unitary matrix $U$ minimizes the Frobenius distance $\|U - X\|_F$?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86539/closest-3d-rotation-matrix-in-the-frobenius-norm-sense/86544#86544

Comment: Same answer applies: if X = WSV is the svd, U = WV is the projection.

Comment: Hi @YoavKallus, thanks for your response. I looked at the text you suggested - their theorem is in terms of polar decomposition, not SVDs. How did you pull out the SVD result? I had already reduced the problem to the case when $X$ is diagonal, using unitary invariance of the Frobenius norm. Intuitively, the identity matrix is the optimal choice in this case, which leads to your result. How do you prove that the identity matrix is the best one when $X$ is diagonal?

Comment: You already have the answer in your own post: for the case of a real nonnegative diagonal matrix, think of the projection to the less strict constraint of normalized rows. If this already lends you in the stricter constraint of unitarity, then the result is also the projection to the stricter constraint. Also, you can get the polar decomposition from SVD and check that the answers agree.

Comment: Have you seen [Kahan's note](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Math128/NearestQ.pdf)?

Comment: @Guatam -- The polar decomposition and SVD for square matrices are "essentially" the same. If A = USV^* is an SVD then A = (UV^*)(VSV^*) is a polar decomposition, and if A = UP is a polar decomposition then A = (UV)(V^*PV)V^* is a singular value decomposition, where V is chosen so that V^*PV = S is a spectral decomposition of P.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the help! @YoavKallus was right, I already had the answer - just forgot a term when doing the optimization!